# PHP foreach cannot echo values

Tags: php, foreach

I am sure that I am missing something that simple, but the following is a foreach loop and if I do a var_dump of $value, then I see all:

```
foreach ($vals as $key => $value) {  
  var_dump($value); 
}
```

The following is a portion of the var_dump:

```
array (size=4)
  'tag' => string 'MAILSERVICE' (length=11)
  'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
  'level' => int 4
  'value' => string 'Priority Mail Express 2-Day&lt;sup&gt;&#8482;&lt;/sup&gt;' (length=57)

array (size=4)
  'tag' => string 'RATE' (length=4)
  'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
  'level' => int 4
  'value' => string '61.15' (length=5)

array (size=3)
  'tag' => string 'POSTAGE' (length=7)
  'type' => string 'close' (length=5)
  'level' => int 3

array (size=4)
  'tag' => string 'POSTAGE' (length=7)
  'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
  'level' => int 3
  'attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'CLASSID' => string '2' (length=1)

array (size=4)
  'tag' => string 'MAILSERVICE' (length=11)
  'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
  'level' => int 4
  'value' => string 'Priority Mail Express 2-Day&lt;sup&gt;&#8482;&lt;/sup&gt; Hold For Pickup' (length=73)

array (size=4)
  'tag' => string 'RATE' (length=4)
  'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
  'level' => int 4
  'value' => string '61.15' (length=5)
```

After seeing those results, I changed the foreach loop to the following, thinking that I was going to just mail service, along with it's rate, but instead just a blank white page:

```
foreach ($vals as $key => $value) {  
  if ($value[$key]['tag'] == "MAILSERVICE") {
    echo $value[$key]['value'];
  } 
  if ($value[$key]['tag'] == "RATE") {
    echo $value[$key]['value'];
  } 
}
```

Using `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Shows undefined index, but those warnings are the same if I just do a var_dump($value)

I know that is has to be something simple that I missing and thanks in advance

Comment: how about `print_r($value, true);`

Comment: The `$key` belongs to `$vals` Either remove it `$value['tag']` or do `$vals[$key]['tag']`

Comment: @Dharman, thank you. I have posted the answer and given you the credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dharman for showing me the light:

```
foreach ($vals as $key => $value) {  
  if ($vals[$key]['tag'] == "MAILSERVICE") {
    echo $vals[$key]['value'];
  } 
  if ($vals[$key]['tag'] == "RATE") {
    echo $vals[$key]['value'];
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$value` is the array composed by the 4 items you provided, the  undefined index is probably `$value[$key]` , i suppose instead of

```
$value[$key]['value']
```

you should use

```
$value['value']
```